# How to prevent divs from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I have several divs that seem to over lap as per the fiddle but want the homemidcontent div to be below the homebanner div? Please help. How do I over come this problem?

Fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/6DtSS/2/)

Markup

```
<div id="homecontent-mid" class="row rounded">
 <div id="homebanner" class="rounded">
    <div class="sliderdiv">Slider Content</div>
    <div class="main-search">Search Content Here</div>
 </div>
 <div id="homemidcontent" class="rounded">
    <div id="home-mid-mid">Mid content here</div>
    <div id="home-mid-right">Mid Content Right here</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#homecontent-mid {
    background: url("images/bg-stage.png") repeat-y scroll right top #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #BDBCBD;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    outline: medium none;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}

#homebanner {
    background: url("images/bg-stage-shade.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.sliderdiv {
    background: white;
    float: right;
}

.main-search {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: medium solid #D51386;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#homemidcontent {
    background: #fff;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#home-mid-mid {
    background: yellow;
}

#home-mid-right {
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6DtSS/5/
I've added `clear:both` to `#homemidcontent`
After you float the elements,you should clear it for the next element if it wants to sit right below.

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for a long time. This is a very easy solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this solution specially clear:both. It helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

Keeping the position you put the blocks in your jsfiddle, you can do that with:

```
z-index: 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/JZAx8/

Choosing the z-index manually you can re-order which one is on top.

Comment: Thanks alot..i prefer the clear:both method to the container. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
You use margin in HOMEIDCONTENT CSS class and change your div position.
```

> ## homemidcontent {
>
> ```
>     background: #fff;
>     padding-right: 20px;
>     position: relative;
>     margin-top:70px;//Write this
> }
> ```

Comment: That's unnecessary,it happened because he didn't cleared the above floated elements.He will eventually run into problems if he don't clear the floats and keep using margins.

Comment: @user2725936 = It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem where I had a button that I wanted to center, followed by a copyright footer at the bottom of the page.

The original code was:

```
<div class="home_button">
            <a href="/home/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            </div>
<div>Copyright...</div>
```

This pushed my button to the left, and scrunched up the copyright next to it.

I added margins to have the button "take up" the entire width:

```
<div class="home_button" style="width:50%;margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%;">
            <a href="/home/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            </div>
<div>Copyright...</div>
```

It now displays properly.